# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'string[]' in windows form

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a function (function1) in my winforms app(c#) that return an array

inside the function1

```
public array function1(string value)
{
string[] array = new string[12];
     //assigning values to the array elements....
retrun array;
}
```

and i call this function like this

```
string id="Some id";
string[] array2 = new string[12];
array2=this.function1(id);
```

but it gives me error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

please experts help me !

Comment: I can't get how it even came to this: error CS0246: The type or namespace name `array' could not be found.

Comment: An "array" as returned by function can be an array of anyuthing; however array2 can ONLY hold references to an array of string. Hence the error. Change the return type of function to string[].

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
public array function1(string value)
```

to

```
public string[] function1(string value)
```

And in your example of usage, you do not need to initialize your array to `new string[12]` before hand, as your function returns a new array anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of function1 should be `public string[] function1(string value)`.
The return type `array` doesn't match the variable of type `string[]`

Answer (score 1):

This works, but not sure what the problem is:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string id = "Some id"; 
    string[] array2 = new string[12]; 
    array2 = this.function1(id);
}

public string[] function1(string value)
{
    string[] array = new string[12];
    array[0] = value; // for example
    return array;
}
```